# how to synchronize addition from different threads using lock-free code?

Tags: c#

I've wrote simple example of `NasdaqIndex` calculation. For simplicity I declared it as `int` and this is just sum of prices of `10` stocks.

```
class NasdaqIndex {

private int[] stockValue = new int[10]; // for simplicity let's assume they are already initialized

// just sum from 1 to 10 of stockValue
private int nasdaqIndexValue; // for simplicity let's assume that already initialized

public void StockValueUpdated(int stockValueIndex, int newValue) {
    int diff = newValue - stockValue[stockValueIndex];
    stockValue[stockValueIndex] = newValue;
    nasdaqIndexValue += diff;               // THIS NEED TO BE SYNCHRONIZED!
}

}
```

But in real life StockValueUpdated may (and will) be called parallel from different threads for different stockValueIndex (it will not be called parallel for the same stockValueIndex).

So I just have to synchronize only one line of code `nasdaqIndexValue += diff;`

For example if one thread executes `nasdaqIndexValue += 10;` and another thread executed `nasdaqIndexValue += 3;` I need to be sure that tottally exactly `13` is added. Do I need synchronization in this case at all? If so how to do that using `lock-free` code?

**UPD** oooops I just realized that using such code I introduce small "delta" to nasdaqIndex every time if I'm using doubles. So I have either use decimal or I have to "recalculate completely" nasdaqIndex sometimes, otherwise it will not be equal to sum of stocks after a while.

Comment: Integer operations are atomic, but I'm not sure how far that goes...

Comment: Why does it need to be lock free?

Comment: @CharlieKilian because it would be faster

Comment: @minitech but we have 2 integer operation `a = a + b` is not atomic operation I guess

Comment: @javapowered: That's what I'm finding out; I don't know if that would be optimized to an atomic operation. Or maybe I'm just confused this morning and it obviously won't work :) Anyway, your "synchronized" and "lock-free" requirements are incompatible.

Comment: @javapowered Are you completely sure the `lock` would slow it down to the point that using one is unfeasible? I'm thinking of the guideline that you shouldn't optimize before you've profiled...

Comment: @CharlieKilian yes I profilied, i was using `BlockingCollection` and that introduce `18 mcs` delay, while with `lockfree` code I only have `2 mcs` delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Interlocked` type to make that operation as atomic:

```
Interlocked.Add(ref nasdaqIndexValue, diff);
```

Comment: but in real life I need to do that for decimals. If this is possible?

Comment: I see it seems it's possible to use `double` http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cd0811yf

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) keyword.

> The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by
>   multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access.

```
private volatile int nasdaqIndexValue; // for simplicity let's assume that already initialized
```

Comment: i'm not sure if this will help. `Interlocked.Add` sounds exactly as what I need

Comment: Interlocked will work but so will volatile. I like volatile because it doesn't "interfere" with the readability of the code.

Comment: I didn't see you were using this with double/decimal in your real world scenario, so yeah volatile won't work with that.