# stock exchange index should be double or decimal?

Tags: c#, real-time, hft

I'm calculating, say, NASDAQ, index.

All stocks prices are decimal
I can make weight decimal or double - it doesn't matter.

nasdaq = weight1 * stock1 + weight2 * stock2 + .... + weightn * stockn.

As stock price is decimal it seems it makes sense to make nasdaq index decimal. But i do not want to recalculate nasdaq index every time some stock is updated. Instead I want to "cache" previous value and then only calculate difference. For example if stock2 is changed, then:

```
stock2OldPrice = stocks[2];
diff = stock2 - stock2OldPrice
nasdaq += diff * weight2     // need to synchronize
stocks[2] = stock2
```

Now I need to synchronize nasdaq index because stocks can be updated at the same time. For example I can receive in parallel threads new price for MSFT and INTC. So I have to write `Interlocked.Add(ref nasdaq, diff * weight2);` refer to my previous question [how to synchronize addition from different threads using lock-free code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11345634/how-to-synchronize-addition-from-different-threads-using-lock-free-code)  However I can not do that for `decimal` because decimals are not supported.

Ok, lets try to declare `nasdaq` index as `double`? With doubles I can do `Interlocked.Add` but now another problem: cause on every step I will convert from decimal to double I will lost precision. And then my "smart caching algorithm" will not absolutely "precise". It means that after 100 000 000 of updates value of my index become completely wrong I can't deal with that.

So it is not possible to use nor `double` neither `decimal`.

I do see only one possible solution - I have to declare nasdaq index as `decimal` so I can keep using my "smart caching algorithm" and so I have to use more complex "synchronization" mechanism, likely I have to use spinlocks.

Probably you can see simpler solution?

Comment: The simple solution would create a better cache solution.

Comment: Have you actually benchmarked this? It seems like all of the synchronization overhead is going to outweigh any potential gains from your caching system. It also obfuscates the meaning of your code. I would personally just create a STOCK type and use LINQ: nadaq = stocks.Sum(s => s.WeightedValue);

Comment: @itsme86 it doesn't make sense to sum everything every time when only one component is changed, right? in hft seriosly I want to do exactly as much as I have to do and not more.

Comment: @Ramhound what would be better cache?

Comment: I agree with @itsme86. The NASDAQ-100 index (the on most used for tracking the nasdaq) only has 100 stocks in it. Summing all those stocks would probably be faster than using spin-locks and caching. Even if you used all 2700+ stocks, it still would be pretty speedy.

Comment: @javapowered You wouldn't sum everything every time a component changed; you'd only do it when you need the final value (i.e. several components could change between queries). You could even store the latest sum and use a "dirty" bit to indicate a component changed and the value needs to be recalculated.

Comment: @itsme86 using dirty bit is too expensive as I do not want to spent time to synchronize things